# Compare and Swap on a 2D Array

Tags: c++, multithreading, multidimensional-array, atomic, compare-and-swap

I'm trying to write to a 2d array (float**W) atomically from different threads. However CAS always gives this error: incompatible type for argument 1 of __sync_bool_compare_and_swap

`c = __sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&W[uu][i], a, b);`

It works fine as usual when I write atomcially to a 1d array.

Any ideas on how to make this work? I can try making 1d arrays in each thread and then updating this 2d array after a barrier, but that would take up too much memory. I'm using Ubuntu/Linux.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that CAS functions support floating-point. Whether it's in a 2D or 1D array is irrelevant, as you only pass in a single element to the function.

Comment: Actually it does support float, i tried a float* array and it worked.

Comment: Sorry, I don't believe you. The function doesn't know whether what you passed in is part of a 1D or 2D array.

Comment: Hmm....maybe the machine i'm using supports atomic floats?

Comment: Again, the fact that this didn't compile shows that it doesn't. You may not have tried exactly what you think you tried in the 1D case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
main() {
  int* W = malloc(10);  
  int uu = 1, i = 3;
  __sync_val_compare_and_swap(&W[uu], 1, 2);
}
```

Compiles fine, however:

```
main() {
  float* W = malloc(10);  
  int uu = 1, i = 3;
  __sync_val_compare_and_swap(&W[uu], 1.0f, 2.0f);
}
```

Does not compile giving me the exact same message you wrote. Which suggests that floats are not supported:

> The definition given in the Intel documentation allows only for the
>   use of the types int, long, long long as well as their unsigned
>   counterparts. GCC will allow any integral scalar or pointer type that
>   is 1, 2, 4 or 8 bytes in length.

and it looks like this confirms that.

If you're not using itanium then maybe

> The four non-arithmetic functions (load, store, exchange, and
>   compare_exchange) all have a generic version as well. This generic
>   version works on any data type.

you might use `__atomic_compare_exchange*` because these should work on any types according to the docs. I haven't tried that yet though.

**Edit:**

```
main() {
  float* W = malloc(10);  
  float target;
  float val = 5.0f;
  __atomic_exchange(&W[4], &val, &target, __ATOMIC_RELAXED);
}
```

^- this at least compiles.